# No internet connection on Virtualbox after upgrading to Virtualbox 5.2.0

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox

I upgraded VirtualBox 4.3.6 to 5.2.0 r118431 (Qt5.6.2) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. After the upgrade, the network stopped working for all my virtual machines (Windows 7 and Kubuntu 16.04). What could be the issue?

Upgrading to VirtualBox 6.0.6 didn't solve the issue.

---

I checked that the network is activated on each  virtual machine:

[image]

[image]

The "virtual box host-only network" is enabled on the host:

[image]

What I see on the Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate guest:

[image: all]

I disabled my firewall.  Virtual machines created after the upgrade are also affected. I've already rebooted the host VM since the VBox upgrade.

On the Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate host, I see that the `VirtualBox Host-Only Network` has "no Internet access": that's likely to be the root of the issue:

[image]

Output of `ipconfig /all`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\FD>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : FD-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : mit.edu
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : corp.adobe.com
                                       mit.edu

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : corp.adobe.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client V
irtual Miniport Adapter for Windows x64
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-05-9A-BB-7A-00
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3558:acef:fe:ca7f%21(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5639:5db4:2d7a:5565%21(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.177.28.149(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.224.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
                                       10.177.33.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 855639450
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-33-49-71-8C-89-A5-02-91-47

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.4.242
                                       153.32.14.241
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Plugable Ethernet
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 8C-AE-4C-F8-E7-3C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #
2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0C-D2-98-02-38-30
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0C-D2-92-09-38-30
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 135
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0C-D2-92-08-38-2F
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d07f:b2a0:7a42:256a%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.24.1.247(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, October 23, 2017 10:19:51 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, October 24, 2017 2:19:54 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.24.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.0.2.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 336384658
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-33-19-70-8C-89-A5-02-91-47

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       4.4.4.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 8C-89-A6-02-91-47
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-31
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4515:65a8:de91:d601%49(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 822738983
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-33-49-70-8C-89-A5-02-91-47

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{F7F563AC-FB24-4229-9E92-B9DAC1F54171}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{53E7CB64-E52D-45A8-A51E-65EBBBC680E0}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{F91F4A4C-1736-461B-B4F9-B39E853B6351}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.corp.adobe.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : corp.adobe.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{46D09D35-E8C2-4F2E-B7AE-74D155D356EA}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I also tried to enable the DHCP on the virtual box host-only network on the host, but it didn't help:

[image]

[image]

Reinstalling VirtualBox and [resetting all VirtualBox preferences](https://superuser.com/q/1262146/116475) didn't help.

The network works fine with VMware Workstation Pro 14.0.0.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=85371
- https://redd.it/7b86kx

Comment: Check the network adapters the VM uses it trusted and not unidentified just in case. I know you said you disabled FW and I assume that was on the host server too. I assume the "virtual box host-only network" is enabled on the host too. I assume you already rebooted the host VM too since the upgrade just in case it's something as simple as that. Disabling and enabling the host network adapters and then doing the same from each VM may be worth a shot too. Quick ideas for you.

Comment: @Facebook Thanks for the suggestions. On the Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate host, I see that the `VirtualBox Host-Only Network` has "no Internet access": that's likely to be the root of the issue. Any clue as to why `VirtualBox Host-Only Network` has "no Internet access" is welcome. I tried Vbox 5.2.0 and Vbox  5.1.30.

Comment: The TCP/IP adapter configurations would cause this is my guess. I see the VM network host adapter has not default gateway for example so packet skating across to a different subnet may not be able to be routed properly for example. I noticed you have `Autoconfiguration Enabled` with a value of "Yes" so maybe try setting the NIC for DHCP or setup a static including default gateway manually.

Comment: @Facebook thanks. I've just tried to enable the DHCP on the virtual box host-only network on the host, but it didn't help. How should I setup a static including default gateway manually?

Comment: I'm not in front of my machine that has Virtual Box to look at it with more detail. I assume the default gateway IP address should match the IP address of the host server but I'm not going to be around a VB instance for a couple days since I'm in a conference. Try bridging the network but keep note on what you change so you can change it back if it doesn't help. If I recall correctly mine was set to NAT like yours but it showed DG but don't remember what it pointed to like the host IP address or what.

Comment: @JakeGould thanks, unfortunately downgrading to 5.1.0 didn't fix the network issue :/

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me several times (and *still* happens) with a Linux guest on a Windows 7 Professional host machine, with your same symptoms, including the inability to fix the situation even rebooting both machines. I have had this since last year, I've upgraded VirtualBox several times, now am on 5.1.30 r118389 (Qt5.6.2), and it still happens around once or twice a month (I use the VM daily).

After various voodoo attempts, I simplified the ritual down to these two steps:

- set the adapter to a different one (I use my Dell WiFi port)
- wait about 8-10 seconds (if I ping 8.8.8.8 in the Linux guest I see that it starts responding)
- set the adapter back to the original wired Intel one
- after 8-10 seconds the ping resumes, and I have connectivity.

[image]

My conclusion was that for some reason some internal structure in the network layer gets stuck into an incorrect configuration, and switching it to and fro fixes whatever it is that got stuck.

I'd love to know the real cause, but I can live with the current situation.

Comment: Thanks! "set the adapter to a different one (I use my Dell WiFi port)" -> in the guest, right?

Comment: In the Virtualbox settings. I always mix up the meanings of host and guest. I'd say in the host, the ouside machine. Sorry, English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure we're talking about the same settings, are you referring to the settings specific to a virtual machine, or the global preferences of virtualbox?

Comment: The settings of the virtual machine. I'm adding a screenshot...

Comment: sorry I got confused as in your answer it sounds like you can change the VM's adapter while the VM is running, which I believe is impossible (can you do it? I cannot.). Anyway, I tried changing the VM's adapter, starting the VM, shutting down the VM, changing the VM's adapter back to the original one, and starting the VM: unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Yes, I can change the adapter without powering down. From the Devices menu. I mean, I can change what physical adapter the VM one is connected to.

Comment: I see, I hadn't realized you were using the bridged adapter. Unfortunately your solution doesn't seem to fix my issue. Do you also see `no network access` when you look at the property of the `VirtualBox Host-Only Network`(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAeVE.png)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. The status dialog says there is no internet access, and the activity counter says 43 Mb sent, 122 Mb received after 1h46m24s of activity. I use this interface to move files between the host and the virtual machine (192.168.5.x), but Internet to the VM goes through the bridged adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Encountered similar situation after upgrading from 5.1.30 into 5.2.0. Downgrade back to 5.1.30 recovered networking. So my suggestion is to use 5.1.30 version until 5.2.x stabilizes a bit more.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately downgrading to 5.1.30 didn't fix the network issue :(